# What encoding standard for strings does Solidity use?

Tags: solidity, encoding

My contract name has an apostrophe, and when deployed it shows on Etherscan as John Doe's Contract instead of, 'John Doe`&#39;`s Contract'.

I tried the UTF-8 \x27, and it also outputted `&#39;`. I even tried converting to hex and using the unicode modifier, but it still renders as that. No luck. Are there any possible workarounds?

Comment: Can you show an example of the contract code? Etherscan is a closed source block explorer so they can show whatever they want.

Comment: It might just be them. The string shows fine in Remix, and on the frontend. I emailed them. The code is simply a normal string. 

There's no code, it's just a string misformatted. I was wondering if it related maybe to Solidity 8 rules for string literals, but I think your instinct is correct. I will update the answer if they reply affirmatively. Other questions have had similar problems, but with resolutions. I tried all of those.

Comment: Have similar problem with adding revert message, any chance you found out how to solve this?

Comment: Nope, it definitely is their problem. Sigh.